# How to create an installer package for java application along with database created in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, installation

I have completed a java application. Now I have to generate an installer package for the application. It also has a database made in mysql. How can i generate an installer along with my database that created in mysql.

Comment: Netbeans has a built in tool that will export to windows EXE, Mac DMG, and Linux DEB...

Comment: Can I embed my database along with it?

Comment: Any reason you are using mysql? It isn't a very good choice for an application, because the user using your application will need MySQL installed on their computer, whereas something like SQLite does not require that, and is much more portable.

Comment: But I have alraedy created database using mysql. Also I am using NetBeans IDE 7.3.1. Does it support generating .exe file? If so Could you tell me how is the process

Comment: i did use advance installer for same reason.we can add mysql java as prerequisite so that they will be installed automatically before deploying main application.however to load database i had created another java program which loads sql file using Runtime for executing mysql.exe from java program. I had also added this application as prerequisite after mysql install.

Comment: Could you tell me how is the process. I have downloaded Advance Installer. But I don't know how to use it

Comment: 1> create new java installer project.  2> go to prerequisite section by clicking prerequisite at left panel. 3> Right click on pre-install and select add new package prerequisite. 4> Select jdk or jre setup exe. 5> repeat process for mysql installer and finally go to `files and folders` section and copy your jar and lib folder(if u have!) in it. After that just build the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To package a program in Netbeans, you may first need to enable it.

1. Right click on your project and go to `Properties`
2. Under `Build -> Deployment` Make sure that `Enable Native Packaging` is enabled
3. Save and close the `Properties` window

You will also need to install 1 or both of the following (For windows builds):

- http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php - EXE
- http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514 - MSI

Now to build the installer:

1. Right click on your project and go to `Package as` and select how you want to package it.
2. Answer the questions it asks and build

You can find more information here: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html